# Trouble Understanding URL Rewrite to Proxy to Another Server

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I am sorry if this is really simple and I am not paying attention. I need to redirect a url query (https://1.2.3.4:19999/abc/start?userid={digit string}) to be processed by another server (https://5.6.7.8/operate?service=checkuser&userid={digit string}).
So far I've failed to do this correctly (this is my latest attempt):

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/abc/start?
    RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*) https://5.6.7.8/operate?service=checkuser&userid= [P]
```

Please can someone correct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need the first condition because the rewrite rule takes care of that. You can try this rule here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} userid=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?abc/start$ https://5.6.7.8/operate?service=checkuser&userid=%1 [P]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works somewhat, but that is my fault, I am sorry I didn't fully define the problem. There is a string of digits that  I need to pass along from the old to the new URL ((https://1.2.3.4:19999/abc/start?userid=01234567891233 should become https://5.6.7.8/operate?service=checkuser&userid=01234567891233, and similar). Right now what is being proxied is  https://5.6.7.8/operate?service=checkuser&userid=start . I am not sure what to change.

Comment: Wow. It does work! Could you please explain to me how it does?

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're asking about, the rule or proxying. For the proxy, you should take a look here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p. The rule just captures the value of the query string using regex and then provides that value (backreference) in your rewriterule which is passed with your substitution URL.

Comment: Was the rule I was curious about.  Thanks!